# Selecting cell references based on value of other cell and can be filled right

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking to write a formula that returns a value based in a cell determined by the value of another cell, and want to be able to fill the formula to the right so the the cell is returning the value from the same row.

Cell B1 has one of 4 values (e.g. "A", "B", "C", or "D")
if B1 = "A" then I want B5 to return the value from B10, while if B1= "B" I want B5 to return the value from B20, etc.
I can do this using a combination of INDIRECT and VLOOKUP (ie `=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(B1,{"A","B10";"B","B20";...},2,0))`
but when I fill the cell to the right, the lookup values don't change, and it won't accept direct references from within the array.  I thought of building a utility table , but this was running into the same problems. The other approach I considered is a nested IF, but this gets cumbersome.
Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use e.g. the SWITCH function:

```
=SWITCH(B1,"A",B10,"B",B20,"C",B30,"D",B40)
```